# BrokenProcessPool Error Raised When Trying to Optimize

Tags: optimization, multiprocess

(I apologize, in advance, if I'm describing my problem terribly and for my lack of jargon knowledge. I'm a quantum computing physicist, just starting with machine learning!).

I'm trying to run an optimization method (krotov.optimize_pulses) where I define a function that calls another function:

```
def eps0(t, args):
        T = tlist[-1]
        return 4 * np.exp(-40.0 * (t / T - 0.5) ** 2)

def transmon_hamiltonian(Ec=0.386, EjEc=45, nstates=8, ng=0.0, T=10.0):
    """Transmon Hamiltonian

    Args:
        Ec: capacitive energy
        EjEc: ratio `Ej` / `Ec`
        nstates: defines the maximum and minimum states for the basis. The
            truncated basis will have a total of ``2*nstates + 1`` states

        ng: offset charge
        T: gate duration
    """

    Ej = EjEc * Ec
    n = np.arange(-nstates, nstates + 1)
    print(n)
    up = np.diag(np.ones(2 * nstates), k=-1)
    do = up.T
    H0 = qutip.Qobj(np.diag(4 * Ec * (n - ng) ** 2) - Ej * (up + do) / 2.0)
    H1 = qutip.Qobj(-2 * np.diag(n))
    
    return [H0, [H1, eps0]]
```

and then I create my "objectives" variable to which I send as an argument in krotov.optimize_pulses.

```
objectives = krotov.gate_objectives(
    basis_states=[psi0, psi1], gate=X, H=H
)

opt_result = krotov.optimize_pulses(
    objectives,
    pulse_options,
    tlist,
    propagator=krotov.propagators.expm,
    chi_constructor=krotov.functionals.chis_re,
    info_hook=krotov.info_hooks.print_table(
        J_T=krotov.functionals.J_T_re,
        show_g_a_int_per_pulse=True,
        unicode=False,
    ),
    check_convergence=krotov.convergence.Or(
        krotov.convergence.value_below(1e-3, name='J_T'),
        krotov.convergence.delta_below(1e-5),
        krotov.convergence.check_monotonic_error,
    ),
    iter_stop=5,
    parallel_map=(
        krotov.parallelization.parallel_map,
        krotov.parallelization.parallel_map,
        krotov.parallelization.parallel_map_fw_prop_step,
    ),
)
```

The first error it raises is "AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'eps0' on <module '**main**' (built-in)>" followed by "BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending."

Any ideas on what how to debug this?

I've tried using multiprocess/Pool but I don't understand the mechanics behind it!